# Data at the root level is invalid even when not using xml file

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to run this code:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static int Main()
    {
        int i; 
        int basee;
        for (basee = 2;; basee += 1) {
            for (i = 2; i < basee; i++) {
                    if ((basee % i) == 0)
                    break;
            }
        if (i == basee)
            Console.WriteLine(basee);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

However, when I try to compile this code with `dotnet build prime.cs`, it results in the error `Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.`.

From a google search, this error comes up when an XML file is invalid, but I am not doing anything with an xml file here.

Does anyone have the solution for this? Am I running the wrong command in cmd? I have tried csc but I get an error that it is not installed, when I have both dotnet core and framework installed between my two pcs.

Comment: How are you compiling this? Normally you have a csproj inside an editor like VS or VSCode. Are you trying to compile it manually with `csc`?

Comment: Try a clean build.

Comment: `dotnet build` expects a project file, not a CS file.  It's opening your .cs file expecting XML.  That's why you're getting the XML-related error message.

Comment: @Amy I cannot csc it either though

Comment: @Chadderbox How are you trying to use `csc`?  You need to use a project file with `dotnet build`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't, you can create a project first using the command [dotnet new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new). Below creates a new console application in .NET Core. The -n parameter specifies the name of your project.

```
dotnet new console -n Prime
```

With your new project you can start developing a console application. Once you're done creating your app, you can run it while in the project directory:

```
dotnet run
```

and build your project using the [build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build) command:

```
dotnet build
```